# Meteor JS: How do I assign the results of Meteor.call to a variable?

Tags: javascript, collections, meteor

I am trying to insert a documents into collections which are all related to each other: `Posts`, `Comments`, and `Categories`. Each document in `Comments` and `Categories` must have a `PostId` field.

I have created a method named `insertSamplePost`, which should return the id of the post after inserting a document into `Posts`. I have assigned this method call to a variable like so:

```
var postId = Meteor.call('insertSamplePost', samplePost, function(error, id) {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } else {
    return id;
  }
});
```

However, when I try to use postId later to insert related comments and categories, it appears to be undefined! Does anyone know what is happening?

Here is my full code:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Template.post.events({
    'click .new-sample-post' : function (e) {
      var samplePost = {
        title: "This is a title",
        description: "This is a description"
      };

      // Insert image stub
      var postId = Meteor.call('insertSamplePost', samplePost, function(error, id) {
        if (error) {
          console.log(error);
        } else {
          return id;
        }
      });

      // This returned undefined. :-()
      console.log(postId);

      var sampleComment = {
        body: "This is a comment",
        postId: postId
      };

      var sampleCategory = {
        tag: "Sample Category",
        postId: postId
      };

      Comments.insert(sampleComment);
      Categories.insert(sampleCategory);
    }
  });
}

// Collections
Posts = new Meteor.Collection('posts');
Comments = new Meteor.Collection('comments');
Categories = new Meteor.Collection('categories');

// Methods
Meteor.methods({
  insertSamplePost: function(postAttributes) {
    var post = _.extend(postAttributes, {
      userId: "John Doe",
      submitted: new Date().getTime()
    });

    return Posts.insert(post);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do:

```
var myVar = Meteor.call("methodName", methodArg, function(error, result) {
  return result;
}
```

Your `myVar` variable will actually be whatever `Meteor.call()` returns, not what your callback function returns. Instead, what you can do is:

```
var postId;
Meteor.call('insertSamplePost', samplePost, function(error, id) {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } else {
    postId = id;
  }
});
```

However, as Akshat mentions, by the time the callback function actually runs and asynchronously sets the `postId`, your `insert` calls on the other collections will already have run.

This code would actually be a little simpler if you avoid the server method altogether - you can modify the document in your collection's `allow` callback:

```
Template.post.events({
  'click .new-sample-post' : function (e) {
    var samplePost = {
      title: "This is a title",
      description: "This is a description"
    };

    var postId = Posts.insert(samplePost);

    var sampleComment = {
      body: "This is a comment",
      postId: postId
    };

    var sampleCategory = {
      tag: "Sample Category",
      postId: postId
    };

    Comments.insert(sampleComment);
    Categories.insert(sampleCategory);
  }
});
```

Now you can add the `userId` and `submitted` fields in your `Posts.allow()` callback:

```
Posts.allow({
  insert: function(userId, doc) {
    doc.userId = userId;
    doc.submitted = new Date().getTime();
    return true;
  }
});
```

If you wanted, you can still do the two secondary `insert`s within the callback for your first `insert`, in order to make the operation more atomic (in other words, to make sure the secondary `insert`s don't happen if the first `insert` fails).

Comment: Oh nice, I did know about the Posts.allow() callback! Why is it better to avoid the server method call altogether?

Comment: Well see my edited code - you don't have to do your secondary `insert`s inside a callback with this approach if you don't want to. There's nothing wrong with using a server method call, but this particular operation can be done with just the plain database API. In my opinion, it makes the code a bit more readable.

Comment: Oops, I meant I *didn't* know about Posts.allow() callback. Bad typo. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Session` to store the results since `Session` is reactive and client side javascript is asynchronous so you cant assign the result to a variable directly using `return`.

So the reason you get undefined is because the result of Meteor.call is given in the callback. The callback will yield a result much later and by the time it returns a result the rest of your code will already have run. This is why its a good idea to use Session because you can use it in a template helper.

However for inserting a post its better to just insert the comments and category in the callback itself since you're not displaying the result in the html.

```
Meteor.call('insertSamplePost', samplePost, function(error, postId) {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
    } else {
      var sampleComment = {
        body: "This is a comment",
        postId: postId
      };

      var sampleCategory = {
        tag: "Sample Category",
        postId: postId
      };

      Comments.insert(sampleComment);
      Categories.insert(sampleCategory);
    }
});
```

This way if the result is an error the comment and category wont be inserted.

Comment: Ah that makes sense, thanks! Another approach I just tried was to generate a unique object `var postId = new Meteor.Collection.ObjectID()._str` and use this as an attribute for the new Post, as well as for comments and categories. This seemed to work too.